# Using knockout.js with custom template engine

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, vis.js

I'm trying to get the [timeline component of vis.js](http://visjs.org/timeline_examples.html) work together with knockout.js.

The timeline has a [templates option](http://visjs.org/docs/timeline.html#Templates) which allows you to write custom HTML for each event on the timeline. In my case, it looks like this:

```
var options = {
    ... // other options
    template: function(item) {
        var html = '<b>' + item.subject + '</b>'+
                '<p>' + item.owner.username + ' (' + item.format.name + ' for ' + item.channel.name + ')</p>' +
                '<p><input type="checkbox"';
        if (item.done !== null) {
            html += "checked"
        };
        html += '></p>';
        html += '<pre data-bind="text: $root"></pre>';  // http://www.knockmeout.net/2013/06/knockout-debugging-strategies-plugin.html
        return html;
    }
}
```

All data bindings are tested and OK, but I cannot think of a way to attach knockout behaviour to the template generated by the vis.js timeline library. As you see, even trying to print out the $root data doesn't do a thing.

How can I attach observables to this template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The template property of the options for the timeline component allows you to provide an HTML element instead of an HTML string if you so wish. This could be one way to achieve what you are after. This way you could create the element, use knockout to apply bindings on the element (and its children) using the provided item as context and return that element to vis.js.

An example of doing this could use code similar to the following:

```
var templateHtml = '<div data-bind="text: content"></div>'
//Set the template to a custom template which lets knokcout bind the items
options.template = function(item){
    //Create a div wrapper element to easily create elements from the template HTML
    var element = document.createElement('div');
    element.innerHTML = templateHtml;
    //Let knockout apply bindings on the element with the template, using the item as data context
    ko.applyBindings(item, element);
    //Return the bound element to vis.js, for adding in the component
    return element;
};
```

In a knockout world, it would of course be *better to create a custom bindingHandler* for the vis.js timeline component.

Therefore, here you also have a sample of doing similar using a custom bindingHandler for knockout (which is a very simple sample bindingHandler, not really supporting observable options or observableArray for data, but it does support observable values in the items).

```js
ko.bindingHandlers.visTimeline = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor){
        var unwrappedValue = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());
        var data = ko.unwrap(unwrappedValue.data);
        var options = ko.unwrap(unwrappedValue.options);
    
        if (options.templateId){
            var templateId = ko.unwrap(options.templateId);
            var templateHtml = document.getElementById(templateId).innerHTML;
            //Set the template to a custom template which lets knokcout bind the items
            options.template = function(item){
                //Create a div wrapper element to easily create elements from the template HTML
                var element = document.createElement('div');
                element.innerHTML = templateHtml;
                //Let knockout apply bindings on the element with the template, using the item as data context
                ko.applyBindings(item, element);
                //Return the bound element to vis.js, for adding in the component
                return element;
            };
        }

        //Apply the vis.js timeline component
        new vis.Timeline(element, data, options);
        //Let knockout know that we want to handle bindings for child items manually
        return { controlsDescendantBindings: true };
    }
};

var items = [
    { id: 1, content: 'item 1', counter: ko.observable(0), start: '2014-04-20'},
    { id: 2, content: 'item 2', counter: ko.observable(0), start: '2014-04-14'},
    { id: 3, content: 'item 3', counter: ko.observable(0), start: '2014-04-18'},
    { id: 4, content: 'item 4', counter: ko.observable(0), start: '2014-04-16', end: '2014-04-19'}
];

var viewModel = {
    items: items
};

//Randomly increment the counters of the items, to see that the data is bound
setInterval(function(){
    var randomItem = items[Math.floor(Math.random() * items.length)];
    randomItem.counter(randomItem.counter() + 1);
}, 500);

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

```html
<!-- First, let's include vis.js and knockout -->
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vis/3.12.0/vis.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vis/3.12.0/vis.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<!-- This is the template we want to use for our items -->
<script type="text/html" id="myCustomTemplate">
    <strong data-bind="text: id"></strong>. <span data-bind="text: content"></span>
    <div data-bind="text: counter"></div>
</script>

<!-- And this is where we use our bindingHandler -->
<div data-bind="visTimeline: { data: items, options: { templateId: 'myCustomTemplate' } }"></div>
```

You can also see this snippet at http://jsbin.com/lecidaxobo/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: I've added a checkbox to the containers and run into another problem. See http://jsbin.com/vidaviroci/1/edit and try clicking the checkbox. Only by disabling events (the `selectable`option) can the checbox be clicked. (I'll move this to a seperate question if needed).

Comment: @LaundroMat Indeed, having clickable things in those containers do not work immediately, due to how vis.js hijacks all the click events, it seems. It's possible to click the checkboxes by pushing the button down, moving the mouse _within the confines of the checkbox_ and then releasing the button. This is not a solution to the problem, only shows that the checkbox works and that it's the click-handling of vis.js that is the problem. However, you are completely correct that it should be handled as a different question. Please link to that question in a comment here, for reference.

Comment: Thanks for the follow up; I've posted my question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29651781/how-to-prevent-the-vis-js-timeline-component-from-hijacking-events-while-using-k